# How to register an EC2 Instance with an ELBV2?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to register a new EC2 instance with an ELBV2. I'm trying from the AWSPowershell Module but cannot get it to work.

```
$InstanceId = (Invoke-WebRequest 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').Content
Register-ELB2Target -TargetGroupArn 'arn:etc...' -Target $InstanceID
```

The error is:

```
Register-ELB2Target : Cannot bind parameter 'Target'. Cannot convert the "i-redacted" value of type "System.String" to type
"Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.Model.TargetDescription".
```

I've checked the documentation, and can see that it can take a port too (optional). Have tried adding the port, but still no luck.

Comment: This sounds like a data type error. Make sure you are converting the data object to the correct type as documentation says. Are you sure you should be using instanceid directly and not the object data? check a sample: https://www.yobyot.com/aws/how-to-register-and-deregister-ec2-instances-by-name-from-an-elb/2015/01/09/

Comment: Indeed it was a data type error, I just couldn't figure out how to correct it though! 
I have sorted it now, with 
    $Instance = New-Object Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.Model.TargetDescription

if you post an answer along these lines it's yours...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not creating the TargetDescription object correctly, it should be something like:

```
$thisInstance = New-Object Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.Model.TargetDescription
$thisInstance.Id = $instanceId
$thisInstance.Port = 80
```

For anyone else who arrives here looking for an easy answer, we use the following script for instances to register themselves with the ALB when new packages are deployed:

```
Set-DefaultAWSRegion "ap-southeast-2"

# work out the id and load balancer for this instance
$instanceId = (wget -UseBasicParsing "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id").Content
$targetGroupArn = (Get-EC2Tag -Filter @{Name="resource-id"; Values=$instanceId}, @{Name="key";Values="<name of key>"}).Value # instances have the alb arn tagged in when created by an autoscaling group

$thisInstance = New-Object Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.Model.TargetDescription
$thisInstance.Id = $instanceId
$thisInstance.Port = 80

write-host "Adding $instanceId to $targetGroupArn"

# register instace with ALB
Register-ELB2Target -TargetGroupArn $targetGroupArn -Targets @( $thisInstance ) -Force

write-host "Done"
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's the same as @CamM's answer, but with shorter syntax:

```
Register-ELB2Target -TargetGroupArn $targetGroupArn -Target @{ Id = $instanceId; Port = 80 }
```

Comment: could this be a comment to the other answer?