# Unable to register targets on AWS Target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-alb

I am trying to setup an automated DNS deployment using powershell. I have written a  powershell script that creates TargetGroup, registers instances to the TG, creates an ALB and adds a listener to it. Once, that is done, it creates R53 RecordSet and creates an A record to the ALB DNS.
I am having issues in having the instances registered to the TargetGroup.
This is my code snippet to that section:

```
$searchFor1 =@( @{name = 'tag:Name'; values = $target1})
$searchFor2 =@( @{name = 'tag:Name'; values = $target2})

$id1 = (Get-EC2Instance -Filter $searchFor1).Instances | select InstanceId
$id2 = (Get-EC2Instance -Filter $searchFor2).Instances | select InstanceId

# Create Target Group

$tg = New-ELB2TargetGroup -TargetType "instance" -HealthyThresholdCount 4 -Name $custname -Port $siteport -Protocol "HTTP" -UnhealthyThresholdCount 4 -VpcId $vpcid
Start-Sleep -s 120
$addid1 = New-Object Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.Model.TargetDescription
$addid2 = New-Object Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.Model.TargetDescription
$addid1.Id = $id1.InstanceId
$addid2.Id = $id2.InstanceId
$addid1.Port = $siteport
$addid2.Port = $siteport
$tgarn = (Get-ELB2TargetGroup -Name $custname).TargetGroupArn
Register-ELB2Target -TargetGroupArn $tgarn -Target @($addid1)
Register-ELB2Target -TargetGroupArn $tgarn -Target @($addid2)
```

It throws below error:

```
Register-ELB2Target : An instance ID must be specified
At C:\scripts\Distinct-DNS-Deployment.ps1:107 char:1
+ Register-ELB2Target -TargetGroupArn $tgarn -Target @($addid1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...LB2TargetCmdlet:RegisterELB2TargetCmdlet) [Register
   -ELB2Target], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cm
   dlets.ELB2.RegisterELB2TargetCmdlet
```

I have checked a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395691/how-to-register-an-ec2-instance-with-an-elbv2). And the corresponding posts, so far nothing helped. I am wondering if anyone can guide me what am I doing wrong?

I have tried to run each line one by one and that happens to register the instance to the TargetGroup, just the script fails.
Instances are t2.micro and they are in running state.

Comment: Are you sure there is something actually returned from the search of the instances: $addid1.Id = $id1.InstanceId <-- this line should be verified --- I could visualize the error 'An instance ID must be specified' only in case if $addid1.Id is $null not have valid instance id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/ElasticLoadBalancingV2/TTargetDescription.html - 
the    Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.Model.TargetDescription  is about 'Information about a target' - 
which means, you should be assigning a single instance id    Also, if you take a close look at the properties:

AvailabilityZone    System.String

Id  System.String

Port    System.Int32

The result of your instance search may or may not be single output - you should keep them in loop to create each target via TargetDescription

```
$Instances = (Get-EC2Instance -Filter @{Name="tag:auto-delete";Value="no"}).instances |select instanceid

$theVpc = get-ec2vpc -VpcId vpc-4565e5c4
$name = "new-tg"
$port = "80"
$protocol = "HTTP"

$tg = New-ELB2TargetGroup -TargetType "instance" -HealthyThresholdCount 4 -Name $name -Port $port -Protocol "HTTP" -UnhealthyThresholdCount 4 -VpcId $theVpc.VpcId
$tgarn = (Get-ELB2TargetGroup -Name $name).TargetGroupArn

If($instances -ne $null){
    foreach ($instance in $instances ){
        $addid1 = New-Object Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancingV2.Model.TargetDescription
        $addid1.Id = $Instance.instanceid
        $addid1.Port = $port
        Register-ELB2Target -TargetGroupArn $tgarn -Target @($addid1)
        Remove-Variable addid1
    }
}
else {
    echo "There were no instances with the matching filter"
}
```

Comment: Hello, The issue was how the targets are being looked at. I had $target = $target.ToLower(). Which was returning the name tag all in lowercase, whereas the actual instance name tag had 1st character uppercase. The $addid1.id was thus returning null value. After rectifying that, I was able to register targets. Thanks KS for your insight as well, I will try it out as an alternate way to address this.